# How to re-initialize requirejs after append HTML content into document?

Tags: magento2, ajax, requirejs, requirejs-config.js

I try to added `HTML + RequireJS` to  `DIV` tag via ajax loading.

With content contain tags like `<script type="text/x-magento-init">` or `data-mage-init` attribute, It's easy to bind event using `$('#selector').trigger('contentUpdated')`. In the case, it can be re-initialize on `mage/apply/main` using function:

```
    function init(el, config, component) {
      require([component], function (fn) {

        if (typeof fn === 'object') {
            fn = fn[component].bind(fn);
        }

        if (_.isFunction(fn)) {
            fn(config, el);
        } else if ($(el)[component]) {
            $(el)[component](config);
        }
      });
   }
```

And I know we can be switch `<script> require(...)</script>` on append HTML to `<script type="text/x-magento-init">`.

But I want to try another way to re-init requirejs. Any ideas for this issue?

Comment: Can you explain why you want to re-init require JS please? It sounds like a strange thing to want to do, or I'm not understanding the question.

Comment: In some case, I want to re-used require js on content like `<script type="text/x-magento-init">`  and don't bind new event for it.